# $p$th Variation

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, probability-theory

Let $f:[a, b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.  When we speak of total variation, every function must have total variation that exists and is nonnegative, although it may be $+\infty$.  Let $p>1$.  Define the $p$th variation of $f$ over the partition $\pi=\{a=t_0, t_1, \dots, t_n=b\}$ to be given by

$T^f_\pi=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} |f(t_{j+1})-f(t_j)|^p$

and set

$T^f=lim_\pi T^f_\pi$.

The meaning of that limit is taken in the directed set of all (Finite) partitions ordered by refinement.

Unfortunately, it is not possible to replace the limit with a supremum because the monotonicity property is lost in the finite approximations when $p>1$.

I am interested in knowing whether this limit always exists in $[0, \infty]$, and whether it exists if some special sequential notion of limit is used.  For instance, when one studies local martingales, their square has actually finite $p=2$ variation, although the limit must be taken along a subsequence of partitions (or otherwise a nonpointwise notion of convergence must be used).